# Bash Search Deep

Tags: bash, loops, random, find

Currently I am using the below commands to find all files in my directory to find all JPG files, however, I want to find extensions .JPG and .GIF as well. I have some files nested under a few sub sub sub folders... How do have this command pull out everything for me? Any help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

```
FILES=/home/pictures/s/downloaded/*.jpg
for randomvid in $FILES
do

done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find path -type f -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.gif' -print
```

This searches for jpg, gif files recursively under the sub-directories of path and returns them

You can process them using the loop.
As Etan pointed out, while loop is better for processing files than for.

```
find path -type f -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.gif" \) -print |
while read FILE
do  
  # Process the $FILE
done
```

Comment: how can I point a directory for it to search if i'm running via cronjob as root?

Comment: can we ignore case sensitive for the extensions?

Comment: You can pass the path where search should start as an argument to your shell script that runs under cron. Then within the script, you can pass $1 as path to find, like so: find $1 -name '*.jpg'

Comment: If your version of find command supports, -i option, you can use it to make search case insensitive

Comment: What is the exact command line for which your are getting syntax error?

Comment: `/test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
./test.sh: line 6: `echo $FILE'`

Comment: Can you post the whole code of the script? Just from line 6, it is not clear what the issue is.

Comment: `for FILE in $(find /root/pictures/ -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.gif'); `
`do`
`echo $FILE`
`done`

Comment: I tried the following script and it worked for me:      #!/usr/bin/ksh

SEARCHDIR=$1

for FILE in $(find $SEARCHDIR -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.log'); do
  echo $FILE
done

Comment: [Don't read lines of data with a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Are there spaces in the names of files or directories?

Comment: @Ramana this works great now, however it doesn't return `.jpg` when there are a buch... but it does return `.gif`

Comment: changed the last part to `-type f \( -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.gif" \) -print |` works great now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a grep sample without piping...

```
grep -rl --include=*.{jpg,gif} "*" ~/pictures/s/downloaded
```

Comment: this somewhat works, but it's giving me datetime as well

Comment: i just want the full path to that file name

Comment: ahh yes, but it also give me directory with .jpg in it... how can i not show directories...

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting directories... you shouldn't be.

Comment: Just a small remark, but shouldn't your grep criteria be `".jpe?g|.gif|.png"` ?

Comment: @Ploutox ... Good catch. Yep.